# Selenium page source return is different than browser view page source. Unable to find body with selenium and python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to enter the postcode from this page - https://woolworths.com.au/shop/catalogue.

I can inspect the input box and it shows the details but if I view page source it does not show.

What is happening here? How can I get to the input box in the main body which is dynamically created.

I have successfully scraped from Salesfinder.com.au site the details of the catalog items, but the Woolworths site has more item details to extract.

The code I have started with is

```
    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
    from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
    from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
    from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
    from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
    from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
    import time
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    
    
    options = Options()
    user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/116.0.5845.96 Safari/537.36'
    options.add_argument('user-agent={0}'.format(user_agent))
    options.binary_location = "H:/programming/chrome-win64/chrome-win64/chrome.exe"
    driver_path = "H:/programming/chromedriver-win64/chromedriver-win64/chromedriver.exe"
    
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
    action = ActionChains(driver)
    
    driver.get("https://www.woolworths.com.au/shop/catalogue/view#view=list&saleId=51690&areaName=NSW")
    time.sleep(4)
    page_source=driver.page_source
    time.sleep(3)
    print(page_source)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page_source, 'lxml')
    print (soup)
    #from sqlalchemy import create_engine
    #URL = 'https://www.woolworths.com.au/shop/catalogue'
    #soup = BeautifulSoup(page_source, "html.parser")
    #books = soup.find_all("div", class_ = "book-item")
    #postcode = driver.find_element(By.ID,'wx-digital-catalogue-autocomplete').send_keys('2750, Woolworths Emu Plains')
    time.sleep(3)
    #selectdown=driver.find_element(By.ID,'wx-digital-catalogue-autocomplete_option--0').click()
    #soup = BeautiulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")
    #print(page.content)
    driver.quit()
```

Comment: When you use the "View page source" menu option, that usually shows you the source of a freshly loaded copy of the current url, instead of showing the actual source of the current page.

Comment: So how do I get to the content that is not returned with the request, but still displays and can be inspected?

Comment: Use "inspect element", not "view page source".  That will show you the actual html of the current page, instead of loading a fresh default copy of the current page.

Comment: @JohnGordon, thanks for that. I was using page source as the main template and inspection for granularity. No need for page source, just straight into the elements. I now have 2 options. Woolworths or SalesFinder. Now to move on to Coles and Aldi's.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, you don't need selenium. You can search via API by, say, location, for example, `Sydney` and then using the `storeId` to query another API endpoint to get your items.

Of course, if you already know the store id, you can skip the search part and plug the id in to the `query_api_url`.

Here's how to do it:

```py
import requests

api_key = "w00lw0rth5A48E69B9C93E236B"
api_url = (f"https://webservice.salefinder.com.au/index.php/api/regions/search/"
           f"?apikey={api_key}&format=json&location=Sydney")

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) "
                  "AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) "
                  "Chrome/115.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/115.0.1901.200",
    "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest",
}

payload = {
    "apikey": api_key,
    "format": "json",
    "location": "Sydney",
}


def get_sale_items():
    with requests.Session() as session:
        search = session.get(api_url, headers=headers, json=payload)
        search.raise_for_status()
        stores = search.json()["items"]
        for store in stores[:1]:
            store_id = store["items"]["storeId"]
            query_api_url = (f"https://webservice.salefinder.com.au/index.php/"
                             f"api/sales/retailer/?id=126&apikey={api_key}"
                             f"&format=json&storeId={store_id}")
            query_payload = {
                "id": "126",
                "apikey": api_key,
                "format": "json",
                "storeId": store_id,
            }
            query = session.get(
                query_api_url,
                headers=headers,
                json=query_payload,
            )
            query.raise_for_status()
            print(f"Found {query.json()['total']} items for store {store_id}")
            results = query.json()["items"]
            for result in results:
                print(result["items"]["saleName"])
                print(result["items"]["downloadLink"])


if __name__ == "__main__":
    get_sale_items()
```

For `Sydney` and the first location in `items` you should get this:

```
Found 2 items for store 4922
Weekly Specials Catalogue NSW
https://dduhxx0oznf63.cloudfront.net/uploads/pdf/WW_NSW_300823_RimJj48b8.pdf
Spring Health & Beauty NSW
https://dduhxx0oznf63.cloudfront.net/uploads/pdf/WW_HBB_NSW_300823_wqc3vyAz.pdf
```

Comment: 1. When trying to register for the API only @woolworth.com.au email addresses or within the group are accepted to get an api key.
2. This is simply downloading the pdf versions of the catalogues, not the data rich web site.
I may try to reverse engineer some more but was able to get to the site last week but not this week.

Comment: Also this is for Salesfinder not woolworth. I have completed the scaping of the catlog list from salesfinder but want to do the same directly on the Woolworths site as it is more data rich, with things like item codes which are the barcodes of the items, catagories, etc.